# Why the shell return the balance normal but php not?

Tags: php

I am using the `easybitcoin.php` library and in my application. I use the `getreceivedbyaddress` method in php. It returns 0, but in my shell when I use bitcoin-cli it returns 0.000000000.

My question is, how can I return in php the same as the shell?

Tried this, `$ data2 = shell_exec ('bitcoin-cli getreceivedbyaddress address');` and it returns 0.00000000, but is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more of a PHP question versus bitcoin, but that's how PHP handles a zero float. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

```
$var = 0.00000000;
echo $var;
```

Returns:

```
0
```

If you want to force a zero value to eight decimals you can use `number_format()` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format

```
$var = 0.00000000;
$formatted = number_format($var, 8);
echo $formatted;
```

Returns:

```
0.00000000
```

Comment: thnx @m1xolyd1an, a question, my application need connect with the api blockchain.com or can i only work bitcoin core?

Comment: Yes you can build an application with just bitcoin-core.